# What are the exact strengths and weaknesses of each TF2 class?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I know that everyone class in Team Fortress 2 has a strength and weakness but I could not find a list on the internet at all. I know that by default, there are three sections: offensive, defensive and support. But each character has some unique ability to them. A list of what each of them are good at and bad at will be very helpful. A link to a page would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a strategy on what to do for each class or just abilities?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The strategy pages on TF2's wiki most likely provides everything you're looking for. Here's a couple sentences from each page that sums them up quite nicely.

**[Scout:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Scout_strategy)** The Scout is the fastest and arguably the most mobile class in the game. He counts as two players when capturing control points or pushing Payload carts, making him ideal for completing mission objectives quickly.

**[Soldier:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Soldier_strategy)** The Soldier is a tough, all-purpose assault class that excels at both offense and defense. Although slow on foot, he can rocket jump to cover distances quickly and reach unpredictable locations.

**[Pyro:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Pyro_strategy)** The Pyro is a moderately tough class that specializes in close range combat and excels at ambushing enemies with his various flamethrowers. The afterburn he inflicts will steadily damage fleeing foes, making him decent at hit-and-run tactics. His compression blast is extremely disruptive and can be used to reflect projectiles, extinguish burning team mates, or forcibly shove enemies around.

**[Demoman:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Demoman_strategy)** The Demoman is a hardy class that specializes in indirect combat and area denial. His Stickybomb Launcher can be used to set traps and easily destroy Engineer buildings.

**[Heavy:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Heavy_strategy)** The Heavy is the largest, toughest, but slowest class in the game. His large size and slow speed makes him a juicy target, especially for enemy Snipers or Spies, and his general loudness makes him subpar at ambushing.

**[Engineer:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Engineer_strategy)** The Engineer has the unique ability to construct Buildings. Although he possesses a weaker set of weapons, his Sentry Gun is more than enough to fend off multiple enemies. His Teleporter system sends teammates to the front lines, while his Dispenser heals and supplies ammunition.

**[Medic:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Medic_strategy)** The Medic is arguably the most important class on a team. Although he only has average health and mediocre firepower, his ability to heal and overheal teammates using the Medi Gun makes him invaluable. Additionally, the Medic continually builds an ÜberCharge meter as he heals others.

**[Sniper:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Sniper_strategy)** The Sniper excels in picking off enemies from great distances. His ability to headshot lets him deal severe damage to foes before they can even get close. He is one of the weakest classes at close range combat and is often targeted by classes that operate alone, such as Scouts and Spies.

**[Spy:](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Basic_Spy_strategy)** The Spy specializes in deception and excels at punishing mistakes made by the enemy team. Although he is fragile and possesses some of the weakest weapons in the game, he can backstab enemies and sap Engineer buildings. The Spy will almost always operate behind enemy lines, using Cloaking and disguises to move about undetected.